# Sort solutions obtained with the resolution of a system

Tags: sorting

After the resolution of a system of 4 equations, i obtained these solutions :

```
   {{m1 -> -0.0137578, 
  m2 -> -0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> -3.13938, \[Alpha]2 -> 
   0.00585403}, {m1 -> -0.0137578, 
  m2 -> 0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> -3.13938, \[Alpha]2 -> -3.13574}, \
{m1 -> 0.0137578, 
  m2 -> -0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> 0.00221465, \[Alpha]2 -> 
   0.00585403}, {m1 -> 0.0137578, 
  m2 -> 0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> 0.00221465, \[Alpha]2 -> -3.13574}}
```

How can I keep only the solutions with the parameters `m1` and `m2` positive (because `m1` and `m2` are masses)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add the constraints `m1 > 0 && m2 > 0` to `Solve` or `NSolve` and the solutions will adhere to the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i keep only the solutions with the parameters m1 and m2
>   positive

```
sol = {
   {m1 -> -0.0137578, m2 -> -0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> -3.13938, \[Alpha]2 -> 0.00585403}, 
   {m1 -> -0.0137578, m2 -> 0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> -3.13938, \[Alpha]2 -> -3.13574}, 
   {m1 -> 0.0137578, m2 -> -0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> 0.00221465, \[Alpha]2 -> 0.00585403}, 
   {m1 -> 0.0137578, m2 -> 0.00520478, \[Alpha]1 -> 0.00221465, \[Alpha]2 -> -3.13574}
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and now

```
 Cases[sol,{Rule[m1,n_],Rule[m2,m_],___}/;n>0&&m>0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So only one solution meets the conditions.

Comment: Thank you Nasser perfect, is the syntax n>0&&m>0 equivalent to {n>0,m>0} ?

Comment: @Bendesarts good question. But  using `{n>0,m>0}` did not work here, the condition must be `n>0&&m>0`